# How can I save the DES encrypted string correctly?

Tags: java, encryption, des

I'm using DES to encrypt a certain `String s1`.
After `s1` is encrypted into `byte[] b1`, I want to save it as a `String s2`.
But when I try to turn `s2` back into `byte[] b2` and decrypt it into the original `String s1`, an error occurs:

> javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher

```
CipherTest ct = new CipherTest();
byte[] encoded = ct.encrypt(str, key);
String s1 = new String(encoded);
byte[] b1 = s1.getBytes();
String decoded=ct.decrypt(b1, key);
```

Comment: Be very careful about converting a string to bytes (or vice versa) without an explicit character encoding. (And by that, I mean don't!)

Comment: `new String(encoded)` is wrong, because `encoded` does not contain text. Effectively, `new String(stuff)` only undoes `someString.getBytes()`. You can't just take a random byte array and convert it to a string, unless it's intended for that.

Comment: You could, for example, base64-encode the bytes into a string, if you need to pass around the encrypted data as a string.

Comment: Your title embodies a fallacy. `String` is not a container for binary data. You should either save the `byte[]` array directly, or encode them in some form such as hex, base-64, etc if you must have a `String.`